# Replacing cursor with set based query

Tags: sql-server, cursor, subquery

I want to find count of set of tables. The table names are values in another table.

--like

```
      select count(*) from tablename
```

--tablename is obtained from

```
      select tablename from table1
```

--table1 has around 171 tablenames

I was using cursor to get each table name and select count for each, but it is taking time. Can you please help how to replace cursor code with set based solution?
Below is my cursor code

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

if( OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptablenew') IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
DROP table #temptablenew
END

select * into #temptablenew from table1

declare @srccount int
declare @tablename nvarchar(max);

declare @q2 nvarchar(max);

declare  @id int;

declare my_cursor cursor
local static read_only forward_only

for 

select id,tablename from #temptablenew 

open my_cursor
fetch next from my_cursor
into @id,@tablename
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 



  set @q2 =N'select @srccount= count(*) from '+@tablename+' with (nolock)';

  execute sp_executesql @q2,@PARAMS = N'@srccount INT OUTPUT', 
      @srccount = @srccount OUTPUT

  select  @srccount,@id,@tablename

  fetch next from my_cursor
  into @id,@tablename
  end
  close my_cursor;
  deallocate my_cursor;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @q2 nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @q2 = @q2 + 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, ''' + tablename  + ''' AS TableName FROM ' + tablename  + ' (NOLOCK); '  
FROM table1

--Print @q2
execute sp_executesql @q2
```

Comment: It is not working . This is taking null value while giving selecting q2

Comment: Modified, try now.